# Can an iOS View handle gestures and direct touch events at the same time?

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOS development and instinctively turn towards handling touch events because my code is cross-platform and this maps more closely to other input devices like a mouse. But obviously for multi-touch, it is neater to just use built-in gesture functionality.

However can one do both - track a single touch directly as a kind of cursor, while also supporting pinch, rotate, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can both happen at the same time but they can (and do by default) interact.
 The gesture has properties such as `cancelsTouchesInView` for example which influence which events are sent on to the view. See also `delaysTouchesBegan` which influences which are sent and when.